# iptables trafic limitation not working properly with http

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, http

I'm using those rules to limit/stop port scan.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 10 -j DROP
```

If i run nmap the scan take a very long time and that's good .
The thing that I dont understand is that when i try to load a webpage quickly to trigger iptable ban nothing happen!

Is this a normal behaviour ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Depending on the browser, it can actually reuse the same connection.  I would test with several different browsers at the same time, say firefox, opera, chrome, konqueror, whatever, and see if you get the results you want.  But, with a hitcount of 10, you may still not reach it.  Test with a smaller number and multiple browsers and see if you get it, then after verifying you can raise it back up.

Comment: I'm using this to prevent bruteforcing a password page . Is it possible to modify the rules to achieve this objective ?

Comment: @isoman: I don't think `iptables` is the right place to do this because there is nothing special about the traffic at the IP level that would indicate it's trying to bruteforce a password page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if your goal is to protect a password page, you may want to look at [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).  Basically, it will run a regex against your log files to detect suspicious activity.  At a trigger level, it will automatically insert iptables rules to block that activity.